# R: If statement contains is.null as one of the conditions connected by OR

Tags: r, logical-operators

I have one variable `mat` which is initialed as `NULL`. I have an iterative process that will fill mat under only certain conditions. After this process I check if `mat` has more than certain number of rows, if not, do something else.

I am looking for a clean way to write this condition, ideally, something like `is.null(mat) | nrow(mat) < n`. Although if `is.null(mat)` is `TRUE` and they're connected by OR, the entire statement should be `TRUE`, but `nrow(mat) < n` will give error.

I can work around that by rewriting it into two conditions and copy the `# do something` code into both of the places, but is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
mat = NULL

for(i in 1:10){
  if(runif(1) > 0.8){
    mat = rbind(mat, c(1,2,3))
  } 
}

if(is.null(mat)){
  # do something...
} else if(nrow(mat) < 3){
  # do something...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the short-circuiting version of `|`, which is `||`.

```
is.null(mat) || nrow(mat) < n
```

From the Help:

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.